# Calling Local/Server Node JS Application from Spring Boot Java Web API

Tags: java, node.js, spring-boot, go, exec

we have installed a node js utility on a local machine/server.

using  npm install -g openapi2Arbitaryservice

I can call this utility and it is working fine. It reads a json and create a service api.

```
openapi2Arbitaryservice generateApi myProxySwagSep6 -s ./swagger-petstore.json -d ./aug-2021
```

I want to trigger this when api request comes to the tomcat server with body of JSON. I have a spring-boot application using java 8.

I was trying to use exec method of java to call this locally installed node js application when an api request comes to the server and do the processing

```
  String[] command = { "/bin/bash", "-c", ,"openapi2ArbitaryService", "generateApi",  "myProxySwagSep6", "-s",".swagger-petstore.json", "-d", "./aug-2021" };
              
           p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

But, i get error "Exit Value 127". It seems it's not able to recognise **openapi2ArbitaryService**

Is this a valid use-case for java calling local/server installed application on user api requests. Should this be decoupled using a queue and then handled separately e.g as a docker task.

Is Golang/python suitable for such use-cases please share some thoughts.

thanks in advance !

Comment: in order to fix 127, I would suggest run "env" from java code and compare the output from your user console. you may need to edit your /etc/profile or /etc/bashrc or your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc files. about queue, if openapi2ArbitaryService taking long time to run it is safer to use some JMS or kafka and finish it separate thread. golang python java these are just languages, use which ever you know best.

Comment: ok thanks i am trying it..it works with "-l", "-c" option. doubt is when i invoke openapi2ArbitaryService in a new thread from java spring boot. Considering it's a node utility will this be safe and support multiple executions. Normally i am running this tool in local mode not from  exposing as a webserver call.

Comment: if you are running the node from a non-root user it is probably safe, but if you want to go full safe you need to read https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9188/444120